# Default property value in React component using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I can't figure out how to set default property values for my components using Typescript.

This is the source code:

```
class PageState
{
}

export class PageProps
{
    foo: string = "bar";
}

export class PageComponent extends React.Component<PageProps, PageState>
{
    public render(): JSX.Element
    {
        return (
            <span>Hello, world</span>
        );
    }
}
```

And when I try to use the component like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<PageComponent />, document.getElementById("page"));
```

I get an error saying property `foo` is missing. I want to use the default value. I've also tried to use `static defaultProps = ...` inside the component, but it had no effect as I suspected.

```
src/typescript/main.tsx(8,17): error TS2324: Property 'foo' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<PageComponent> & PageProps & { children?: ReactEle...'.
```

How can I use default property values? Many JS components my company uses rely on them and not using them is not a choice.

Comment: `static defaultProps` is correct. Can you post that code?

Answer (score 428, accepted):

### Default props with class component

Using `static defaultProps` is correct. You should also be using interfaces, not classes, for the props and state.

***Update 2018/12/1***: TypeScript has improved the type-checking related to `defaultProps` over time. Read on for latest and greatest usage down to older usages and issues.

#### For TypeScript 3.0 and up

TypeScript specifically [added support for `defaultProps`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-defaultprops-in-jsx) to make type-checking work how you'd expect. Example:

```
interface PageProps {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

export class PageComponent extends React.Component<PageProps, {}> {
    public static defaultProps = {
        foo: "default"
    };

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <span>Hello, { this.props.foo.toUpperCase() }</span>
        );
    }
}
```

Which can be rendered and compile without passing a `foo` attribute:

```
<PageComponent bar={ "hello" } />
```

Note that:

- `foo` is *not* marked optional (ie `foo?: string`) even though it's not required as a JSX attribute. Marking as optional would mean that it could be `undefined`, but in fact it never will be `undefined` because `defaultProps` provides a default value. Think of it similar to how [you can mark a function parameter optional, or with a default value, but not both, yet both mean the call doesn't need to specify a value](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20optionalParam(param%3F%3A%20string)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20defaultParam(param%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22foo%22)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AoptionalParam()%3B%0D%0AdefaultParam()%3B). TypeScript 3.0+ treats `defaultProps` in a similar way, which is really cool for React users!
- The `defaultProps` has no explicit type annotation. Its type is inferred and used by the compiler to determine which JSX attributes are required. You could use `defaultProps: Pick<PageProps, "foo">` to ensure `defaultProps` matches a sub-set of `PageProps`. More on this caveat is [explained here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#explicit-types-on-defaultprops).
- This requires `@types/react` version `16.4.11` to work properly.

#### For TypeScript 2.1 until 3.0

Before TypeScript 3.0 implemented compiler support for `defaultProps` you could still make use of it, and it worked 100% with React at runtime, but since TypeScript only considered props when checking for JSX attributes you'd have to mark props that have defaults as optional with `?`. Example:

```
interface PageProps {
    foo?: string;
    bar: number;
}

export class PageComponent extends React.Component<PageProps, {}> {
    public static defaultProps: Partial<PageProps> = {
        foo: "default"
    };

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <span>Hello, world</span>
        );
    }
}
```

Note that:

- It's a good idea to annotate `defaultProps` with `Partial<>` so that it type-checks against your props, but you don't have to supply every required property with a default value, which makes no sense since required properties should never need a default.
- When using `strictNullChecks` the value of `this.props.foo` will be `possibly undefined` and require a non-null assertion (ie `this.props.foo!`) or type-guard (ie `if (this.props.foo) ...`) to remove `undefined`. This is annoying since the default prop value means it actually will never be undefined, but TS didn't understand this flow. That's one of the main reasons TS 3.0 added explicit support for `defaultProps`.

#### Before TypeScript 2.1

This works the same but you don't have `Partial` types, so just omit `Partial<>` and either supply default values for all required props (even though those defaults will never be used) or omit the explicit type annotation completely.

### Default props with [Functional Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)

You can use `defaultProps` on function components as well, but you have to type your function to the `FunctionComponent` (`StatelessComponent` in `@types/react` before version `16.7.2`) interface so that TypeScript knows about `defaultProps` on the function:

```
interface PageProps {
  foo?: string;
  bar: number;
}

const PageComponent: FunctionComponent<PageProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <span>Hello, {props.foo}, {props.bar}</span>
  );
};

PageComponent.defaultProps = {
  foo: "default"
};
```

Note that you don't have to use `Partial<PageProps>` anywhere because `FunctionComponent.defaultProps` is already specified as a partial in TS 2.1+.

Another nice alternative (this is what I use) is to destructure your `props` parameters and assign default values directly:

```
const PageComponent: FunctionComponent<PageProps> = ({foo = "default", bar}) => {
  return (
    <span>Hello, {foo}, {bar}</span>
  );
};
```

Then you don't need the `defaultProps` at all! Be aware that if you *do* provide `defaultProps` on a function component it will take precedence over default parameter values, because React will always explicitly pass the `defaultProps` values (so the parameters are never undefined, thus the default parameter is never used.) So you'd use one or the other, not both.

Comment: I've ctrl+c/ctr+v'd your code (and fixed the semicolon that shouldn't be there) and it's giving me the same error: src/typescript/main.tsx(8,17): error TS2324: Property 'foo' is missing in type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<PageComponent> & PageProps & { children?: ReactEle...'.

Comment: The error sounds like you are using `<PageComponent>` somewhere without passing the `foo` prop. You can make it optional using `foo?: string` in your interface.

Comment: Yes, exactly, because I need it to use the default value specified in defaultProps - when I pass the prop in the place where I use it, it gets overwritten, doesn't it?

Comment: You're right, I wasn't thinking, obviously you want it optional. :) Updated my example.

Comment: What if I want to have two properties: one required and one optional with default value? `public static defaultProps` cannot have the type of `PageProps` then, as I'm not going to specify all props required by interface.

Comment: @pamelus You can mix optional and not optional props in a single interface, just mark the optional ones with a `?` and leave the required props as is.

Comment: @Aaron But tsc will throw compilation error then, as defaultProps does not implement PageProps interface. You either have to make all interface properties optional (bad) or specify default value also for all required fields (unnecessary boilerplate) or avoid specifying type on defaultProps.

Comment: Can typescript partials be used with a stateless functional component?

Comment: @adrianmoisa You mean default props? Yes it works but the syntax is different... I'll add an example to my answer when I'm back at my computer...

Comment: @AdrianMoisa Updated with s function component example

Comment: @Aaron I have a very similar question, would you mind help me on [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032289/default-function-value-in-react-component-using-typescript)?  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hi, using this way, inside the component it will complain `"foo" is possibly undefined`, even though we provided default value. How to fix that?

Comment: @Boyang use the "Definite Assignment Assertions" to silence the compiler. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html

Comment: @Boyang Yeah, that's an annoying issue when you have `strictNullChecks` enabled, AFAIK there's no way to make TS understand this correctly. You can always use a non-null assertion: `this.props.foo!` or a type-guard `this.props.foo && /*do something with foo */`. FWIW Flowtype seems to understand `defaultProps` better.

Comment: @Boyang Definite Assignment Assertions are close, those work on instance properties and variable declarations, but component props aren't either of those.

Comment: I logged [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22881) about the case with `strictNullChecks` and there's some workarounds described [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/ultimate-react-component-patterns-with-typescript-2-8-82990c516935) (scroll to "Default Props")

Comment: I know this is an older question, but does `defaultProps` *need* to be a `public static` field or could it be a `private` field?

Comment: @Jared Yes, it needs to to be `public static defaultProps` or `static defaultProps` (`public` is default) for everything (compiler and React runtime) to work properly. It may work at runtime with `private static defaultProps` only because `private` and `public` don't exist at runtime, but the compiler wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: Just the perfect answer!

Comment: The Function Component example appears to not work? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgAUcwBnOAXjgG9y44A7FCHoB+AFxwWMKMH4BzUnF5wAbigA2AVyQSpM+YvIBfSuTQR+UuADEIECcnQwAdNc38MwCwGFckfkj8MAA8TBCsAHwccAAUXILCADSqGtpGAJQcUTzKCUjOMBAAytKycjHpFHxEMJpQ-HDBACbAKgD0ERQm5LYQzk1ImCia6jBhrNE8fHkS+AAWSOrqEPjGpEA

Comment: August, 2023 - https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-optional-props-typescript

Answer (score 23):

With Typescript 2.1+, use **Partial < T >** instead of making your interface properties optional.

```
export interface Props {
    obj: Model,
    a: boolean
    b: boolean
}

public static defaultProps: Partial<Props> = {
    a: true
};
```

Answer (score 19):

#### Functional Component

Actually, for functional component the best practice is like below, I create a sample Spinner component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { colors } from 'helpers/theme';

export interface SpinnerProps {
  color?: string;
  size?: 'small' | 'large' | 1 | 0;
  animating?: boolean;
  hidesWhenStopped?: boolean;
}

const Spinner = ({
  color = colors.primary,
  size = 'small',
  animating = true,
  hidesWhenStopped = true,
}: SpinnerProps): JSX.Element => (
  <ActivityIndicator
    color={color}
    size={size}
    animating={animating}
    hidesWhenStopped={hidesWhenStopped}
  />
);

export default Spinner;
```

If your component has `children` it would be better to use `React.FC`, like following:

```js
export interface TypographyProps {
  color?: string;
}

const Typography: React.FC<TypographyProps> = ({
  children,
  color,
}) => (
  <span style={{ color }}>
    {children}
  </span>
);

export default Typography;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the spread operator to re-assign props with a standard functional component.  The thing I like about this approach is that you can mix required props with optional ones that have a default value.

```
interface MyProps {
   text: string;
   optionalText?: string;
}

const defaultProps = {
   optionalText = "foo";
}

const MyComponent = (props: MyProps) => {
   props = { ...defaultProps, ...props }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is the cleanest, easiest to read solution.

Comment: Might be better to use a temp variable to merge instead of overwriting the parameter `props`

Comment: @jfunk why?????

Comment: "Assignment to variables declared as function parameters can be misleading and lead to confusing behavior, as modifying function parameters will also mutate the arguments object. Often, assignment to function parameters is unintended and indicative of a mistake or programmer error."

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign

Answer (score 10):

With Typescript 3.0 there is a [new solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-defaultprops-in-jsx) to this issue:

```
export interface Props {
    name: string;
}

export class Greet extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        const { name } = this.props;
        return <div>Hello ${name.toUpperCase()}!</div>;
    }
    static defaultProps = { name: "world"};
}

// Type-checks! No type assertions needed!
let el = <Greet />
```

Note that for this to work you need a newer version of `@types/react` than `16.4.6`. It works with `16.4.11`.

Comment: Great answer! How might one handle: `export interface Props { name?: string;}` where name is an _optional_ prop? I keep getting `TS2532 Object is possibly 'undefined'`

Comment: @Fydo I haven't needed to have a default value for an optional prop, since `undefined` is a sort of automatic default value for those props. You want to be able to pass in `undefined` as the explicit value sometimes, but have another default value? Have you tried `export interface Props {name: string | undefined;}` instead? Haven't tried that, just an idea.

Comment: Adding `?` is the same as adding `|undefined`. I want to optionally pass in the prop, and let `defaultProps` handle that case. Looks like this isn't possible in TS3 quite yet. I'll just use the dreaded `name!` syntax since I know it's never `undefined` when `defaultProps` are set. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Upvoted because this is the right answer now! Also updated my accepted answer (which is starting to become a history book) with this new feature, and a little more explanation. :)

Answer (score 5):

From a comment by @pamelus on the accepted answer:

> You either have to make all interface properties optional (bad) or
>   specify default value also for all required fields (unnecessary
>   boilerplate) or avoid specifying type on defaultProps.

Actually you can use Typescript's [interface inheritance](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html). The resulting code is only a little bit more verbose.

```js
interface OptionalGoogleAdsProps {
    format?: string;
    className?: string;
    style?: any;
    scriptSrc?: string
}

interface GoogleAdsProps extends OptionalGoogleAdsProps {
    client: string;
    slot: string;
}


/**
 * Inspired by https://github.com/wonism/react-google-ads/blob/master/src/google-ads.js
 */
export default class GoogleAds extends React.Component<GoogleAdsProps, void> {
    public static defaultProps: OptionalGoogleAdsProps = {
        format: "auto",
        style: { display: 'block' },
        scriptSrc: "//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

For those having optional props that need default values. [Credit here :)](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11640)

```
interface Props {
  firstName: string;
  lastName?: string;
}

interface DefaultProps {
  lastName: string;
}

type PropsWithDefaults = Props & DefaultProps;

export class User extends React.Component<Props> {
  public static defaultProps: DefaultProps = {
    lastName: 'None',
  }

  public render () {
    const { firstName, lastName } = this.props as PropsWithDefaults;

    return (
      <div>{firstName} {lastName}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the functional component, I would rather keep the `props` argument, so here is my solution:

```
interface Props {
  foo: string;
  bar?: number; 
}

// IMPORTANT!, defaultProps is of type {bar: number} rather than Partial<Props>!
const defaultProps = {
  bar: 1
}


// externalProps is of type Props
const FooComponent = exposedProps => {
  // props works like type Required<Props> now!
  const props = Object.assign(defaultProps, exposedProps);

  return ...
}

FooComponent.defaultProps = defaultProps;
```

Comment: defining `FooComponent.defaultProps` makes no sense, because it isn't used. you are **manually** merging the prop directly with the `defaultProps` variable...

Answer (score 2):

With `optional` and `default` props for functional component (Typescript 4.4+):

```
export const LoadingSpinner = ({
  size = "lg",
  children,
}: {
  size?: "sm" | "base" | "lg";
  children?: any;
}) => {
console.log(size);
return <div>{children}</div>
};
```

use it like this:

```
 <LoadingSpinner size="sm"><p>hello</p></LoadingSpinner>
 <LoadingSpinner><p>hello</p></LoadingSpinner>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my solution:

```
interface Props {
  foo?: string | undefined;
  bar: string;
  other?: string;
}

export const Component = ({foo, bar, other = 'default text'}:Props) => {
    console.log(foo, bar, other);
    return(
        ...//some cool stuff your component should do
    )
}

<Component bar='obligatory text'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As we know to do one task, react have many ways, one is I am demonstrating.

Component

```
<Greet name="Dupinder"/>
```

Component Type

```
type greetProps = {
    name: string
    number ?: number
}
```

Assigining default or passed values from component.

```
export const Greet = (props: greetProps) => {
    const {number = 0} = props
    return ( 
        <div>
            <h2>Welcome to the react practice: {props.name} here {number}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Creating a const with default value which will be filled from props coming from component attributes.

[image]

Component with value

Component

```
<Greet name="Dupinder" number="10"/>
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score -1):

## Hooks (with Typescript)

```
export interface ApprovalRejectModalProps{
 singleFileApprove:boolean;
}

ApproveRejectModal.defaultProps={
 singleFileApprove:false --> default value
}

export const ApproveRejectModal:React.FC<ApprovalRejectModalProps>=(props)=>{
return (
        <div>
            ....
        </div>
       )
}
```