# How to set default property values in React with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I set the default values of properties in React components when using with Typescript?

I saw from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37282159/750511) on SE that I could declare a static class variable of `defaultProps` as an object with its keys my properties, but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Somehow, the static variable `defaultProps` wasn't called from anywhere and the properties still don't have their default values.

Comment: Can we have your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? :)

Comment: Could you provide some code? Defining `defaultProps` as static class variable is works for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default property value in React component using TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282159/default-property-value-in-react-component-using-typescript)

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I do it in the constructor:

```
interface iProps {
   value?: any;
   disabled?: boolean;
}

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<iProps, {}> {
   private value: any;
   private disabled: boolean;

   constructor(props: iProps) {
      super(props);

      var value: any = "";
      if (typeof this.props.value !== "undefined") {
         value = this.props.value;
      }

      var disabled: boolean = false;
      if (this.props.disabled) {
         disabled = true;
      }
   }

   handleClick(event) {
      //Bla bla bla
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this) } disabled={this.disabled}>
               my button
            </button>
         </div>
      );
   } //end render.

   componentDidMount() {
      //Bla bla bla
   }

   componentDidUpdate() {
      //Bla bla bla
   }
} //end class.
```

Comment: This code will not work if you first render MyComponent with disabled=true and then remove the prop in the next render.