# TypeScript + React: defining defaultProps correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say you define your component like so:

```
interface IProps {
  req: string;
  defaulted: string;
}

class Comp extends React.Component<IProps, void> {
  static defaultProps = {
    defaulted: 'test',
  };

  render() {
    const { defaulted } = this.props;

    return (
      <span>{defaulted.toUpperCase()}</span>
    );
  }
}
```

when you want to use it, TypeScript wants the `defaulted` prop from you, even though it's defined in `defaultProps`:

```
<Comp req="something" />  // ERROR: TypeScript: prop 'defaulted' is required
```

However, if you define the props interface like so:

```
interface IProps {
  req: string;
  defaulted?: string;  // note the ? here
}
```

then you cannot use it in:

```
render() {
  const { defaulted } = this.props;  // ERROR: prop 'defaulted' possibly undefined

  return (
    <span>{defaulted.toUpperCase()}</span>
  );
}
```

How to define the IProps, defaultProps and component correctly so the types make sense?

**EDIT:**

I'm using the `strictNullChecks` flag.

Comment: *"I have them defaulted"* ...do you?

Comment: I am pretty sure I do: `static defaultProps: IDefaultProps = {
    validate: () => null,
    defaultValue: '',
  };`

Comment: Alright, let me rephrase: they don't appear to be defaulted in the code you show in the question. Give a [mcve].

Comment: If you add the ? (like you have with index) they will be optional and you won't get the error about being potentially undefined. Then, default their value where you use them.

Comment: @Stuart but then I cannot use it within the component - TypeScript complains that they are potentially undefined

Comment: How does `IDefaultProps` relate to `IProps`? That doesn't look like other working examples (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37282264).

Comment: It doesn't because it cannot - ideally, `IProps` should be current `IProps & IDefaultProps`, but then TypeScript wants me to pass `validate` and `defaultValue` as props, ignoring the fact i've defaulted them

Comment: Ok let me adjust the question

Comment: @jonrsharpe better?

Comment: I use optional properties in combination with defaultProps a lot and never encountered the problem that you mention. The only difference is that I access the property value directly instead of first creating the constant. What editor / linter / compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using WebStorm 2016.2, TypeScript 2, TSLint 0.4.0 @BjörnBoxstart. I tried to add full `this.props` prefix and it still doesn't compute

Comment: @ldefixx I'd just cast this problem away: `const defaulted = <string>this.props.defaulted;`.

Comment: You haven't typed `defaultProps`, does that make any difference?

Comment: it does not :( @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an example with the following code (ComponentBase is just my wrapper around React.Component).

**Edit:** updated code to work with 'strictNullChecks' setting

```
interface IExampleProps {
    name: string;
    otherPerson?: string;
}

/**
 * Class with props with default values
 *
 * @class Example
 * @extends {ComponentBase<IComponentBaseSubProps, {}>}
 */
export class Example extends ComponentBase<IExampleProps, {}> {
    public static defaultProps: IExampleProps = {
        otherPerson: "Simon",
        name: "Johnny"
    };

    constructor(props: IExampleProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        const person: string = this.props.otherPerson === undefined ? "" : this.props.otherPerson;
        return(
            <div>
                <h1><small>Message by ComponentBaseSub: Hello {this.props.name} and {person} </small></h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have no issues using Visual Studio Code, TypeScript 2.0.3, TSLint 0.5.39.

Comment: maybe because `{this.props.otherPerson}` is OK to be `undefined`. try to add a variable, say, `const person: string = this.props.otherPerson;` and see if it complains

Comment: @Idefixx Adding exactly that variable to the body of the 'render' method still does not result in the issue you reported.

Comment: You can check my react samples fork on https://github.com/boxstart/react-typescript-samples. Example 02 contains the optional property and defaultProps from my example above. If you still get the warning / error using this project, then you might need to look for a setting in your environment.

Comment: aaaah, I'm using the `strictNullChecks` flag. Try it with that

Comment: Tried it and indeed I'm getting the message too. This isn't really unexpected behaviour, because in the reference to you component (jsx / tsx), it is possible to set the property to undefined and so in your render method the property value would still be 'undefined', despite the default value in the component.

Comment: @Idefixx Please see code update to make it compliant with the strictNullChecks setting.

Comment: ok I understand now - thanks! anyway, a neater solution is `const person: string = <string> this.props.otherPerson;` as another person here suggested.

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart how can it be set to `undefined` when interface requires string? this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @apieceofbart when strictNullChecks is enabled, this indeed shouldn't be allowed, but when strictNullChecks isn't enabled, it is allowed to pass 'undefined' as a value to a parameter of type string.

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart what does `?` means? here `otherPerson?: string;`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet this means that it is an optional property. The 'name' property is mandatory, but the 'otherPerson' property is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler is

```
<span>{(defaulted as string).toUpperCase()}</span>
```

Works the same way with properties. If `Foo` requires the `barProp` property but `Parent` does not and gets it through `defaultProps`, `Parent`'s render method can do

```
<Foo barProp={this.props.barProp as string} />
```

Comment: thanks! null checks with defaultProps defeats the benefit of using defaultProps

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure the prop will have a default value, you can use the null assertion type operator, like this:

```
render() {
  const { defaulted } = this.props;
  return (
    <span>{defaulted!.toUpperCase()}</span>
  );
}
```