# Typescript and React defaultProps are still being treated as possibly undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
interface PageProps {
    foo?: Function;
    bar: number;
}

export class PageComponent extends React.Component<PageProps, {}> {
    public static defaultProps: Partial<PageProps> = {
        foo: () => alert('Did foo')
    };

    private doFoo() {
        this.props.foo(); // Typescript Error: Object is possibly 'undefined'
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>Hello, world! The number is {this.props.bar}</span>
                <button onClick={() => this.doFoo()}>Do the Foo</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to tell Typescript that `props.foo` will *always* be defined?**

There is a very good [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282159/default-property-value-in-react-component-using-typescript) that discusses how to properly define the types for props on a component. It even discusses how you would let TS know about `defaultProps` on a *stateless* component.

However Typescript will still complain inside a regular component definition that your props might be undefined (as illustrated in my example above).

You can call it using a bang (`this.props.foo!()`) and that prevents TS from throwing an error, but it also prevents any kind of type checking on whatever you've passed in. In the example above, not a big deal. In more complex code, it has already bitten me.

So I am currently implementing things like this instead:

```
private doFoo() {
    if (this.props.foo) this.props.foo();
}
```

That has one drawback, which I think is rather important: It makes my code a little confusing. In reality, I *always* want to call `this.props.foo()`, but it seems like, without investigating the class more closely, there are cases where nothing will happen inside the `doFoo` method. (Yes I could add a comment explaining that the `if` is only for Typescript to be happy, but I'd rather my code speak for itself when it can.)

My code becomes even more unnecessarily complex when I actually need to return something from `this.props.foo()`.

I am currently using @types/react for my type definitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, the compiler is saying that the object is possibly `undefined`. You know better that it's not, so you just want to write `this.props.foo()`. The right way to do it is using the null assertion type operator

```
this.props.foo!()
```

If you say that this has bit you before, then that's your own fault for not checking it :), which means the compiler was -right- that the object could have been `undefined`. And if there is a possibility it could be `undefined`, you should always check it. Perhaps you like a more shorter version of the `if` statement? It's one character less:

```
private doFoo() {
  this.props.foo && this.props.foo();
}
```

or with the typescript >= 3.8:

```
private doFoo() {
  this.props.foo?.();
}
```

On the other hand you can make an extra interface which `extends` the `PageProps`. For the fun of it, let's call it `PagePropsFilled`:

```
interface PagePropsFilled extends PageProps {
    foo: Function;
}
```

You can now set your `this.props` to `PagePropsFilled`, and it won't show you an error anymore

Comment: You are my hero today, saved me from doing two interfaces for default props and props... <3

Comment: hmmm but how can the prop be `undefined` when we require type in `interface`?  If you pass `undefined` Typescript should complain that it wants Function, if we don't pass anything, it should get the default value. This is confusing

Comment: @apieceofbart If the interface property is written as `foo?: Function`, this means that any class implementing this interface has the choice to implement the `foo` method or not. If it does not implement it, it will return be `undefined`. In interfaces you cannot have a default value

Comment: @PierreDuc thanks, I understand it now. My idea would probably require some changes to Typescript in order to work with react defaultProps. I still think it's a shame because we need to write checks (`if (this.props.foo)..` for the code that will always be true

Comment: Well, read my given answer. If you are sure that it will always be true, you can use the `null assertion type operator`, like this: `this.props.foo!()`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see the answer to this sooner and accept it. I cannot remember at the moment, but I think that my issue with using the ! was that doing so effectively turned the type into `any`. But I do not remember if that is what I meant. I didn't know TS *nearly* as well then as I do now.