# Default function value in React component using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

The question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282159/default-property-value-in-react-component-using-typescript?noredirect=1&lq=1), but mine is focused on the default function. (I'm new to front-end, please let me know if there's a more official name for it)

This is the code (I'm using TypeScript 2.5):

```
export const TestProps = {
    Hello: (name: string) => {
        console.log(name);
    }
}

type TestPropsType = typeof TestProps;

export class TestComp extends React.Component<TestPropsType, {}>{    
    public render() {
        this.props.Hello("world");
        return <div>test</div>;
    }
}
```

Then, when I try to render this component:

```
ReactDOM.render(<TestComp />, document.getElementById("page"));
```

I got this error；

> TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & ...'.
>     Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ Hello: (name: string) => void; }>'.
>
> Property 'Hello' is missing in type '{}'.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's fix your example:

```
interface TestProps {
    Hello?: { (name: string): void };
}

export class TestComp extends React.Component<TestProps, {}> {    
    public static defaultProps: Partial<TestProps> = {
        Hello: name => console.log(name)
    };

    public render() {
        this.props.Hello("world");
        return <div>test</div>;
    }
}
```

The way that you had it written before meant that your component couldn't see `TestProps` (it wasn't passed in from anywhere) and that `Hello` was a required prop. I used an interface with `Hello?` to make it optional, rather than using `typeof`.

The compiler error came from the fact that `Hello` was required, so you would have needed to use:

```
ReactDOM.render(<TestComp Hello={() => {}} />, document.getElementById("page"));
                       // ^ pass Hello as a prop here
```

Doing this would fix the compile error, but you would still be left with incorrect behaviour, as the object `TestProps` in your example would never be used.

If you are using `strictNullChecks`, then you will have to work your way around the type system a little bit, since `Hello` is an optional property:

```
if (this.props.Hello) this.props.Hello("world");
// or
this.props.Hello && this.props.Hello("world");
```

By checking whether `this.props.Hello` is *truthy*, the type is narrowed from `(name: string) => void | undefined` to just `(name: string) => void`, so you can call the function.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I just tried your solution, but ... now there's another error （there's a red line under the "this.props.Hello"） :   TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.