# How do I establish default props for functional React components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

What is the correct way to define default prop values for functional React components?

Using TypeScript

```
interface ThingProps {
    something?: number;
}

const Thing: FC<ThingProps> = (props: ThingProps): ReactElement => {
    const something = props.something || 0    
    // ...
}
```

lets me write either

```
<Thing />
```

or

```
<Thing something={someValue} />
```

both of which work correctly.

Is this the correct idiom, or does React have a different preferred way to achieve this?

---

Note that while there are [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37282264/656912) about this they are quite old (2016) and none work for me: they result in TS errors with `<Thing />` (missing required property) or on uses of `something` (could be undefined).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default property value in React component using TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282159/default-property-value-in-react-component-using-typescript)

Comment: @EmileBergeron No, I saw that, but the question here is about this specific approach. That answer is from 2016 and things have evolved. The [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37282264/656912) doesn't work for me.

Comment: Then please make sure to highlight what's not working in the other question in your question, like mentioning the TS version you're using. Or put a bounty on the old question to gather up to date answers.

Comment: The [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54479670/1218980) looks like it has what you're missing?

Comment: Specifically the `type PropsWithDefaults = Props & DefaultProps;`

Comment: @EmileBergeron Sorry, maybe the question isn't clear. It's about whether there is a reason not to just do this. Why chose one of those other approaches?

Comment: _"Is this the correct idiom"_ Since you're not defining `defaultProps` and doing your own defaults with `const something = props.something || 0`, you're bypassing React's prop types validation, which works but loses the benefits.

Comment: I'm not using TS, there are probably other reasons, like catching an accidental `undefined` prop value.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Ah, so the issue here is that I'm ducking under React with TypeScript. (The `PropsWithDefaults` approach has that problem, too, no?)

Comment: [The `PropsWithDefaults` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54479670/1218980) defines both interfaces, then merges them into a third type, making it possible to define the `defaultProps` (on his class component example, but similar on a function component). He's then benefiting from both TS and React.

Comment: It looks like [there's no definitive way of doing it](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11640) right now.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Hmmm, indeed! For now, it seems like I can get the best of both worlds by doing what I'm doing (simple TypeScript that's easy to follow and avoids introducing new types/interfaces) and simply add `Counter.defaultProps = { sequence: 0 }` which tells React what I'm up to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set them directly on `Thing`:

```
Thing.defaultProps = {
  something: 0
};
```

Comment: Do I get anything from that that I don't get just using TypeScript? The issue I'm having is that not only does TypeScript on it's own seem to be able to handle this in the obvious way, but `defaultProps` (as well as the other methods mentioned in the 2016 answers) aren't recognized by TypeScript.

Comment: Let’s say `something` was required and not optional like you have it… If a JavaScript app was pulling in that component, your `<Thing />` would set `something` to 0 and wouldn’t throw an error if you left off the prop. But if you are using that `<Thing />` component in a TypeScript app, it would still throw an error because `<Thing />` expects `something` to be a `number`.
I’ll set my defaultProps in a project like a component library, where I’m not sure what type of app is consuming the component.

Comment: Would doing what I've got above and [then adding `Thing.defaultProps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562960/how-do-i-establish-default-props-for-functional-react-components?noredirect=1#comment101589648_57562960) cover me?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign the `props` parameter to a default value (or object with values) in the function declaration:

```
interface ThingProps {
  something?: number;
}

const Thing: React.FC<ThingProps> = (props = {something: 1337}) => {
  return <>{props.something}</>
}
```

Or use the spread operator which I personally find a bit cleaner:

```
interface ThingProps {
  something?: number;
}

const Thing: React.FC<ThingProps> = ({something = 1337}) => {
  return <>{something}</>
}
```

If you don't need to reuse the interface `ThingProps` elsewhere you can even do everything inline:

```
const Thing: React.FC<{ something?: number; }> = ({something = 1337}) => {
  return <>{something}</>
}
```

BTW I'm pretty sure doing

`const Thing: FC<ThingProps> = (props: ThingProps): ReactElement => {`

is redundant vs just doing

`const Thing: FC<ThingProps> = (props) => {`

because you've already typed `Thing` to be a React functional component and typed the props to be `ThingProps` in the variable declaration.