# propType "value" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration react/require-default-props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Since days ago when I run yarn start I have all this error :

```
src/components/Balance.tsx
  Line 13:3:  propType "value" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration   react/require-default-props
  Line 15:3:  propType "unit" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration    react/require-default-props
  Line 16:3:  'prefix' PropType is defined but prop is never used                                   react/no-unused-prop-types
  Line 16:3:  propType "prefix" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration  react/require-default-props
```

I tried everything reset last commit or clone again the repo but I don't understand why I have this error now...

Comment: These are ESLint errors. Check with your team if someone enabled it. If it was not intentional and you don't want these checks you may disable it. Here is a question already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696724/eslint-problem-with-default-props-in-functional-component-typescript-react

Comment: @SanishJoseph thx for your answer ! where can I disable it ? directly from the package.json file or .eslintrc ?

Comment: .eslintrc , Something like this ` "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off"
  },` . But make sure that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have turned on the [`react/require-default-props`](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/require-default-props.md) ESLint rules somehow(maybe by the inclusion of some ESLint plugin) which started giving you the error.

To fix this you can turn it off by setting the below flag in your Eslint config file(which can be `.eslintrc.js` or in some other format mentioned [here](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats))

```
{
  rules: {
    "react/require-default-props": "off"
  }
}
```

Or you can explicitly set the `defaultProps` for your `Balance` react component like below

```
Balance.defaultProps = {
  value: "", // some default value for `value` param
  unit: "", // some default value for `unit` param
  prefix: "", // some default value for `prefix` param
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The warning you're encountering suggests that you have a prop named "value" that is not marked as required (isRequired), but you also don't have a corresponding defaultProps declaration for it. This can be addressed by adding a defaultProps section to your component.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // Prop types declaration
  static propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string, // Not marked as required
  };

  // Default props declaration
  static defaultProps = {
    value: 'Default Value', // Set a default value for the prop
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.value}</div>;
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

In this example, the "value" prop is not marked as required (isRequired), but a default value is provided in the defaultProps section. This will prevent the eslint warning you mentioned and ensure that if the "value" prop is not provided, it will default to the specified value ('Default Value' in this case).