# propType "name" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component with optional props. I'm defining the default values of the optional props by passing them to the Card component, nevertheless eslint keeps telling me `propType "text" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration.` The same goes for the `children` prop. The code below seems to be in line with the example `without defaultProps` on this page: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/require-default-props.md.

```
import { ReactElement } from 'react';

interface CardProps {
  title: string,
  text?: string | (string|ReactElement)[],   // eslint is complaining here
  children?: React.ReactNode                 // and here
}

const Card = ({ title, text = '', children = null }: CardProps) => (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="title">{title}</div>
      <div className="underline" />
      <div className="card">
        <div className="text">
          {text}
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
);
```

My eslint (7.32.0) config is as follows:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx"] }],
        "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "import/extensions": [
            "error",
            "ignorePackages",
            {
              "js": "never",
              "jsx": "never",
              "ts": "never",
              "tsx": "never"
            }
        ],
        "no-use-before-define": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["error"]
    },
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
            "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
            }
        }
    },
    "globals": {
        "React": true,
        "JSX": true
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really weird. That code is just fine, and [TypeScript itself is happy with it](https://tsplay.dev/mx5KxW). What version of ESLint? What's your configuration?

Comment: I'm glad my code is not the problem :p. I added my config to the question.

Comment: What version of ESLint are you using?

Comment: oops, also added

Comment: For lurkers: While `^7.32.0` just tells us that it's 7.32 **or later** in the v7 chain, there wasn't a later v7 release (v7.32 was the last v7 release). So the OP is apparently using v7.32.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### TLDR: Turn off the rule.

I'm also using ESLint 7.32.0 (and TS 4.4.4) and running into the same problem. I've gotten into the weeds on this and found three ways to prevent the ESLint message.

#### 1)

First is to use defaultProps directly, which is [deprecated](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/16210) for function components. In your case it would look like:

```
Card.defaultProps = {
  text: '',
  children: null,
}
```

after the Card function declaration. But this is an anti-pattern.

#### 2)

Second is to [export the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67630849/16335768). It remains a mystery why this works.

#### 3)

Third is to use the [React.FC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64041197/16335768) function typing pattern. This has many [drawbacks](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-why-i-dont-use-react-fc/) and I do not use it, likely for similar reasons to you.

#### Conclusion

None of these techniques are satisfactory, and since defaultTypes has been deprecated it is best to turn off the ESLint rule rather than to reconfigure your code to its liking.

Comment: Turning off the linter for those lines was going to be my temp solution, and now also my final solution lol. Hopefully a fix will come for this some day. Thx anyways.

Comment: Turning it off is the right choice. Just set defaults during prop destructuring.

Answer (score 4):

You can config a `rule` in your `eslintrc.json` the following way and still keep some useful warning, error rule working.

```
...
"react/require-default-props": [
  "error", 
  {
    "forbidDefaultForRequired": true,        
    "functions": "defaultArguments" //Here
  }
]
...
```

More info, see [this](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/require-default-props.md#rule-options)

Comment: This seems better than the accepted answer since the rule is not turned off and can provide useful warnings.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jack mentioned

```
export interface Props {
  children?: ReactNode;
}
```

Exporting the interface worked!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can make the field type union, instead of optional(`?:`), which make field value default as undefined like below:

```js
export interface CardProps {
  title: string,
  text: undefined | string | (string|ReactElement)[],
  children: undefined | React.ReactNode,
}
```

Providing `defaultProps` is not always easy or possible, where some fields might load from files or resources from the server, which in some cases there will be no placeholder, like a file tree...