# React - TypeScript adding undefined to prop even though defaultProps are defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why does the following doing the following:

```
type Props = {
  name?: string
  age: number
}

const Test = FC<Props> = (props) => {
  return (
    <h1>Hello, {props.name}. You are {props.age} years old.</h1>
  )
}

Test.defaultProps = {
  name: "John"
}
```

Give off the warning that `name` could be `undefined` when `strict` mode is set to `true` even though `name` is defined in `defaultProps`.

Comment: Because you're specifying the `name` can be undefined in `Props`

Comment: if you are sure that you will be passing name then remove `?` if not ask me i have a solution

Comment: @MoshFeu I thought the point of passing the `Props` inside `FC` was that you could do that...

Comment: @GayatriDipali not necessarily. `name` has a default value. But if you remove the `?` it will ask for the `name` prop every time you use the component, which is invalid, as it has a default property.

Comment: Nope. it means that `name` can be undefined, therefor the code should consider it. You can remove the optional mark (`?`) because **you** know that name is never undefined.

Comment: @GayatriDipali as I told @MoshFeu that will not work. As it forces you to pass down `name` if you remove the `?` even though it has a default value.

Comment: you could just do this  `<h1>Hello, {props?.name}. You are {props?.age} years old.</h1>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript does not check `defaultProps` for function components. If you want a default value, you should use ES6 default values, as in:

```
type Props = {
  name?: string
  age: number
}

const Test: FC<Props> = ({ name = "John" }) => {

}
```

Comment: it does though... https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-defaultprops-in-jsx

Comment: nvm, i see it's for classes

Comment: Yep, classes behave differently.

Comment: does that mean that the answer here is wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37282264/10040604

Comment: To my knowledge, the section on function components is wrong: defaultProps on a function component does not change the types. Perhaps there's some compiler flag i'm unaware of that would allow it to work.

Comment: @MustKillBill this would be the correct way with typescript as `defaultProps` is being planned for deprecation

Comment: Yeah I figured, I had always used this pattern. But the answer on that question threw me off. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is:

```
{props.name ? props.name : "Jhon"}
```

Comment: This works, but defeats the whole purpose of using `defaultProps` in the first place